# Foo.class what does it do?

Tags: c#, java, class, types

I m looking at some Java code, and there is this code that I see often.

```
Foo.class
```

This is being used to to indicate the Type of the class? is that similar to

```
Foo.GetType();
typeof(Foo);
```

in C# ?

What is it being used for ? and what s the meaning of it?

Comment: Some related info: `System.Type` is a general type in .Net, and not specific to C#. I don't know if the same is or isn't true for the `Class` type in the JVM (as opposed to the Java language itself).

Comment: It's pretty hard finding this piece of information coming from Java. I searched for "c# class object", "c# reference to class" and many other terms not knowing this is called `Type` in C# - the only things you'll get are tutorials and introductions to OOP. But thank you for that Question :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `Foo.class` in Java is equivalent to `typeof(Foo)` in C#. See [section 15.8.2 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2) for more information on *class literals*.

It's *not* the same as calling `GetType()` on a reference, which gets the *execution time* type of an object. The Java equivalent of that is `someReference.getClass()`.

One reason you may see it more often in Java code than in C# is in relation to generics. It's not entirely unusual to have something like:

```
public class Generic<T>
{
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public Generic(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

This allows execution-time access to the class for reflection etc. This is only necessary in Java due to *type erasure*, whereby an object of a generic type can't normally determine its type arguments at execution time.

Comment: great. I find it a little funny that they call it clazz :)

Comment: @user177883: Well, that's one convention. Others may use different names. It's just because `class` is a keyword.

Comment: @user177883, that's because `class` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: yeah, i know it s a reserved keyword, but what s wrong with _class. As Jon mentioned, it should be the convention they are using.

Comment: @user177883: The underscore is what's wrong with `_class` :) In some conventions that would indicate a field name, so you then couldn't use it as a parameter name... and personally I just dislike underscores...

Answer (score 2):

there is special class in java called *Class* . it inherits *Object*. its instance represents the classes and interfaces in java runtime, and also represents enum、array、primitive Java types（boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, double）and the key word *void*. when a class is loaded, or the method defineClass() of class loader is called by JVM, then JVM creates a Class object.

Java allows us to create a corresponding Class object of a class in many ways,
and .class is  one of them.
e.g.

```
Class c1 = String.class;
```