# what is the equivalent of .class (used in Java) in C#

Tags: c#, java, class

In Java :

```
TokenStream my_stream = analyser_exclude.tokenStream(fieldName, my_reader);
TermAttribute my_token = TermAttribute.getAttribute(TermAttribute.class);
```

In VB.NET :

```
Dim my_stream As TokenStream = analyser_exclude.TokenStream("", my_reader)
Dim my_token As TermAttribute = DirectCast(my_stream.GetAttribute(GetType(TermAttribute)), TermAttribute)
```

I just changed the fieldname in VB.NET because I didn't need it. This code works in VB.NET
but I don't know how to change the DirectCast in C# and the last line of code with (in Java) Termattribute.Class

In C# : 
???

Help me please I don't know how to change those lines in C#.

Comment: Here's someone going the other way round: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789924/foo-class-what-does-it-do

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for `typeof`:

```
TermAttribute my_token =
    (TermAttribute)my_stream.GetAttribute(typeof(TermAttribute));
```