# Convert Java byte[].class to c#

Tags: java, c#

Any one know how to convert byte[].class in java to c# ?
I stack on code below:

`Method removeBondMethod = btClass.getDeclaredMethod("setPin", new Class[]{byte[].class});
Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) removeBondMethod.invoke(btDevice, new Object[] {str.getBytes()});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the equivalent of .class (used in Java) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200111/what-is-the-equivalent-of-class-used-in-java-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Note that `byte` in Java is signed, as C# equivalent exists `typeof(byte[])` or `typeof(sbyte[])` for signed byte value.

Answer (score 1):

Type [byte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in Java would be type [sbyte](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm) in C# (both 8-bit signed integer), which means byte[].class becomes typeof(sbyte[]) in C#

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use byte[].GetType()

Comment: No that will not compile because `GetType` needs an object instance.

Comment: type byte in C# is unsigned, but in Java it is signed. Use sbyte instead